# iPhone App - is this possible to Capture and Record Video from External Camera

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have one requirement in my iOS app.

1:- Can we use external camera to capture and Record Videos in my App.

2:- I am sure its not possible connecting external camera through USB without MFi License.

3:- So i want to go for Wifi option.

Please Comments.Any Library and reference would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I owned a Sony QX-100 and had been playing around with their Camera Remote APIs ( https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/ ), a functional example is included and you may reference from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, want to know bit more , did you try these API to Connect other external camera apart from Sony Qx-100 .

Comment: No, I don't own other camera than Qx-100, the sample in the link is not strictly a obj-C SDK, it's just a demonstration using `NSURLRequest` to interact with the camera. if you're using other cameras, of course, you have to actually know the camera-side APIs provided, I'm referencing those codes in `SampleCameraDefinitions.h`, fyi.